# get dotnet to output using ansi escape sequences

Tags: .net, .net-core

so - I'm running a "dotnet test" build on a build server.

The build server understands ansi escape sequences, but doesn't seem to understand whatever dotnet uses, so I don't get coloured output, even though the batch file around it has colours from ansi.

Does dotnet have any weird configuration properties or is there some way of inserting a different console, or any other way of getting ansi colour sequences out of it?

Answer (score 0):

.NET uses UNICODE (16 bit characters) for almost everything. I believe the Windows console is using UTF-8 encoding.

Here's an article someone wrote about what you're trying to do:

https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-ansi-color-codes-in-net-console-apps/

Comment: Could you please post the important/relevant points from the blog post in this answer itself? The link/blog might go away at some point.